Is there a word for acceptance in the context of grief
I am wondering if there is a word for acceptance. By acceptance I mean the calm retrospective feeling you get when you finally come to terms with something, like a breakup or the death of a loved one. I tried looking for translations in dictionaries but the entries were for different usages of the word than the usage I'm looking for.

I'm not sure how familiar German speakers are with the Five stages of grief, introduced in the book On Death and Dying by Elisabeth Kübler-Ross. (She's from Zurich, hence the umlaut, but I'm pretty sure the book is in English.) In any case, German Wikipedia translates gives the five stages as Leugnen (Denial), Ärger (Anger), Feilschen (Bargaining), Depression and Akzeptanz (Acceptance). By rights these terms should be limited to technical jargon, but they've caught the popular imagination in English speaking countries.

The fifth stage of grief by Kübler-Ross is often called Akzeptanz or Annahme.

Thanks for your help!

If "word" is meant to include "phrase" there is:

seinen Frieden machen (mit ...)

which means "come to terms (with ...)". Literally it means "to make one's peace".
There is also

sich in sein Schicksal fügen

but that means "to accept" in the sense of to no longer fight against something - to accept one's fate.
A word carrying the meaning you look for might be

hinnehmen

which means to accept something without seeking any counteraction - to acquiesce in/to sth..
There is of course also

akzeptieren

which is the literal translation of "to accept" with the same meaning as in English.

I like the proposed translations very much, but the question was asking for a noun.

Actually, the question was asking for a "word", not a "noun" and I adressed that possible shortcoming of the answer in the first sentence.

Thanks for the help!
